# Selenium screenshots of the exact same page are slightly different

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, automated-tests, screenshot

As part of our continuous integration system, I am implementing a system to compare screenshots of each page of our project after each commit.

I am using JUnit and Selenium for that purpose. It works quite well, but sometimes the exact same page will result in slightly different screenshots.

I first compare the MD5 hashes of the screenshots, then count the number of different pixels if the hashes don't match. In practice, I often end up with over 5000 pixels that are not the same for the exact same page (resolution is 1280x800). The differences appear around texts.

Here's a "diff" picture, where the pixels that are not the same are highlighted:

[image: difference]

(it's a pixel-by-pixel comparison where the diff is added to the RGB value)

Stripped-down code:

```
File captured = ((TakesScreenshot) webDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(captured, screenshot); // + exception handling
String oldMd5 = hashFile(reference); // previous version of this page
String newMd5 = hashFile(screenshot);
// then compare the hashes...
```

Any idea?

Comment: 5000 pixels for 1280x800 seems to be for ~1 inch display. Are you sure they are opening with the same settings? Do you have the examples of 2 different screenshots?

Comment: @Stanjer I added an image

Comment: So, does that mean you are making screenshots of the specific element? Or you just cut it for stackoverflow? How are you basicly doing the screenshots?

Comment: @Stanjer I cut it for SO since I unfortunately can't show it all. I added some code.

Comment: What if you will try to make a screenshot of only body element? something like https://gist.github.com/fat-troll/ca9d9fe3ff2d7e53ae48 (but add a proper css selector for your website's body)

Comment: Ah, it looks like it only happens when one screenshot is taken on a viewable browser and the other using Xvfb. Maybe it's a resolution or pixel density problem? It's still problematic...

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, if you are running it headless (without viewing the execution) then technically  it will make a screenshot of ~1 inch display (a bit more then 5000 pixels for 1280x800).